# Using rules of inference (Leibniz) to prove theorems.

Tags: logic, proof-writing, boolean-algebra, proof-theory

**Leibniz**: If $A \equiv B$ is a theorem, then so is $C[p:= A] \equiv C[p:= B]$.
Note: p is "*fresh*" means p doesn't occur in $A, B, C$.

I am trying to understand how to use Leibniz rule of inference for my proof. I understand equanimity, and the other axioms and boolean logic. The example below (equational proof) is giving me a hard time.


Prove theorem $A \vee A \wedge B \equiv A$: 
$A \vee (A \wedge B)$
$\Leftrightarrow$ < proven theorem  $(A \wedge T \equiv A)$ + Leib, C-part: $p \vee (A \wedge B)$, p fresh >
$(A \wedge T) \vee (A \wedge B)$
$\Leftrightarrow$ < Distributivity of $\wedge$ over $\vee$ (2.4.23 (ii)) >
$A \wedge (T \vee B)$
$\Leftrightarrow$ < proven theorem $( B \vee T)$ (2.4.7) + redundant true metatheorem +  symmetry of $\vee$, therefore theorem $T \vee B  \equiv T$ + Leib, C-part: $A \wedge p$, p fresh >
$A \wedge T$
$\Leftrightarrow$ < proven theorem $( A \wedge T \equiv A)$ (2.4.20) >
$A$


I dont understand how to go from that first line to the second line. Why are we using Leib on $(A \wedge T \equiv A)$ and not the formula in the fist line? How do you choose what C should be? Also I tried working out Leib on $(A \wedge T \equiv A)$, I got $(A \wedge T) \vee (A \wedge B) \equiv A \vee A \wedge B$, so then why does the following line only take the left side of $\equiv$?

Comment: I assumie you mean "$p$ doesn't occur in $A,B$" (as opposed to $A,B,C$).  Leibniz' rule would be quite useless if your $C$ would not have a $p$.

Comment: A side remark: it strikes me as misleading to refer to the rule "substituting equivalent *statements*  yields equivalents" as *Leibniz's* rule. Leibniz's name is usually associated with a rule about substituting co-referential *terms*.

Comment: @Peter Smith - you are right (of course). See Tourlakis, page 139 : **4.2.1 Definition. (Logical Axiom Schemata of Predicate Logic)** : "This group contains all formulae of the form $t = s \rightarrow (A [x := t] \equiv A[x :=s])$. It is called the 'Leibniz axiom (group) for equality'." I suppose that the reason why ... is simply a (bad) analogy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you this answer.

Using the two identities : $A \equiv A \land T$ and $T \equiv B \lor T$, we have that :

> $A \equiv A \land T \equiv A \land (B \lor T)$

by *Leibniz*.

Using *Distributive law* we have :

> $ \equiv (A \land B) \lor (A \land T) \equiv (A \land B) \lor A$

by *Leibniz*, using again the above identity.

Finally :

> $ \equiv A \lor (A \land B)$

by *Commutativity*.

About the correct understanding of *Leibniz*, I will refer to George Tourlakis, *Mathematical Logic* (2008), taht is based on *equational logic*.

See page 39, **1.4.1 Definition. (Schema Instance)** :

> Here are some examples of schemata:
>
> (1) $A$: It is a formula-metavariable; if we replace the letter "$A$" by some formula, well, we get that formula as the result!
>
> (2) $(A \equiv B)$: This schema has two formula-metavariables, $A$ and $B$. Whatever formulae we may replace $A$ and $B$ with, we get a formula [...]
>
> (3) $A[p := B]$: This schema has two formula-metavariables, $A$ and $B$, and a Boolean metavariable, $p$. Whatever formulae we replace $A$ and $B$ with, and whichever Boolean variable replaces $p$, we get a formula [...].

See also page 40, **1.4.2 Definition. (Rules of Inference)** :

> The following two are our primitive or primary rules of inference, given with the help of the syntactic variables $A, B, p, C$ : [...]
>
> from $\quad A \equiv B \quad $ , infer $\quad C[p := A] \equiv C[p := B] \quad$ *(Leibniz)*.

For the "correct usage" of *Leibniz* you must take into account the difference between the *(meta)-variables* $A$ and $B$, which stay for formulas, and the *(meta)-variable* $p$, which stay for a Boolean letter.

In applying *Leibniz* to the formula

> $A \land B \equiv A$

you must understand that the equivalence is between formulas; when you apply *Leibniz*, you must replace a Boolean letter "contained" into an existing formula (call it *first*) with another formula (call it *second*), obtaining a resulting formula (call it *third*). *Leibniz* says that *third* will be equivalent to *first*.

In our application, we have replaced into the *formula* $A$ (the $C$ of the rule) the *Boolean letter* $A$ (now, the $p$ of the rule) with the *formula* $A \land T$ (the $B$ of the rule, that is equivalent to $A$); this is the reason why : $A \equiv A \land T$.

So, the conclusion is, do not "mix" the different styles of variable in the formulas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Leibniz rule, but it is a rather ricky rule, if you use it with formulas that are not theorems you can go horribly astray, so i think it is more for protection than anything else.

You make it more complicated than it is by trying to do to many steps at once.
better to do it really step by step (and don't worry about using to much paper)

I am not sure which book you use, and every book is a bit different

in this  I use the rules from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equational_logic (and do play around with them as well)

```
1  (A v (A & B)) <-> (A v (A & B))          Theorem
2  (A & T ) <-> A                           Theorem
3  (A v (A & B)) <-> ((A & T)  v (A & B))   1,2 Leibniz
4  ((A & T) v (A & B)) <-> (A & (T v B))    Distribution Theorem
5  (A v (A & B)) <-> (A & (T v B))          3,4 Equanimity
6  (T v B) <-> T                            Theorem
7  (A v (A & B)) <-> (A & T)                5,6 Leibniz
8  (A v (A & B)) <-> A                      2,7 Equanimity
=======================
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Step 5 isn't correct.

Comment: @Willemien - I think that the step 4) is too "hard" to do in a single step. If you want to use *Distributivity*, you will have : $(A \land T) \lor (A \land B)$, that is $[(A \land T) \lor A] \land [(A \land T) \lor B]$, i.e. $[(A \lor A) \land (A \lor T)] \land [(A \lor B) \land (B \lor T)]$, i.e.$(A \land T) \land [(A \lor B) \land T]$, i.e. $A \land (A \lor B)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  Line 4 is an theorem , the proof is a⁮n equational proof,and the OP didn't mention which book was used, so I used Equational logic (see link) , Equational logic is literally only about equalities all other connectives are just uninterpretable signs in the logic,  distribution is not a part of the logic itself and can only be done by introducing theorems like i did on line 4, Ps the same applies to line 2 and 6.

Comment: It is not clear to me why line 3 is *not* derivable from 1 and 2 using *Leibniz*. According to "my source" (Tourlakis) you can apply the rules (*Leibniz* and *Equanimity*) to assumptions. Second: *Transitivity* is a *derived* rule, stated as : $A \equiv B,B \equiv C \vdash A \equiv C$; so, how can you apply it to 1 and 2? Third: your proof (if I'm not wrong) looks like : $A \lor (A \land B) \vdash A$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA You  are right about the Leibniz rule (corrected in the proof) I also made the proof more axiomatic.

Equanimity a derived rule? probably it is but can you give a proof of it?

Proof of implication not of equivalence?,
No, see new proof (in equivalence logic you can only proof equivalences, but maybe you were confused about the assumption, it is gone now) 

I don't have Tourmalis book, what are his axioms ?

Comment: @Willemien - the *primitive* rules of Tourlakis (page 40) are *Leibniz* and *Equanimity*. The axioms are : Associativity and Simmetry of $\equiv$, Associativity, Symmetry and Idempotency of $\lor$, Distributivity of $\lor$ over $\equiv$, Excluded Middle, Golden Rule, Implication (i.e.$A \rightarrow B \equiv A \lor B \equiv B$), Introduction of $\lnot$ (i.e.$\lnot A \equiv A \equiv \bot$) and Properties of $\bot, \top$ (i.e.$\top \equiv \bot \equiv \bot$).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Those formula's are unreadable , add some "(" and ")", i think Tourlaki is a bit flexible with what equational logic is $\land , \lor , \to , \bot , \top $ are not really part of it , (I know, I also use them) will have  a look later again.

Comment: @Willemien - you can see the hardcopy attached to some post by the OP. The formula are exactly like Tourlakis, and parentheses are **not** there.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use *Natural Deduction*, working with assumption is much easier :

*(a)* we prove the "direction" : $A \rightarrow ...$

a.1) assume $A$

a.2) $A \lor (A \land B)$ --- from a.1) by $\lor$-intro

a.3) $A \rightarrow (A \lor (A \land B))$ --- from a.2) by $\rightarrow$-intro, discharging a.1).

*(b)* we prove the "direction" : $... \rightarrow A$

b.1) assume $A \lor (A \land B)$

b.2) assume $A$

b.3) assume $A \land B$

b.4) $A$ --- from b.3) by $\land$-elim

b.5) $A$ --- from b.1), b.3) and b.4), by $\lor$-intro, discharging b.2) and b.3)

b.6) $(A \lor (A \land B) ) \rightarrow A$ --- from b.5) by $\rightarrow$-intro, discharging b.1).

we have now :

> $A \rightarrow (A \lor (A \land B))$

and

> $(A \lor (A \land B) ) \rightarrow A$

and the equivalence is proved.